# Systemd docker container service does not work with CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, docker

Here is the service (/etc/systemd/system/docker-mysql.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=MySQL container
Author=Me
After=docker.service

[Service]
User=root
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
ExecStart=/bin/docker start -a wpic-seo-mysql
ExecStop=/bin/docker stop -t 10 wpic-seo-mysql

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I run it with:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start docker-mysql.service
systemctl enable docker-mysql.service
```

Service works with manual start command but not at the boot time when I restart the server.
I use CentOS 7 and Docker v1.3.2.

Here is the error:

```
Feb 27 15:10:31 iZ23bojyn7vZ docker[847]: [01038d66] -job container_inspect(wpic-seo-mysql) = OK (0)
Feb 27 15:10:31 iZ23bojyn7vZ docker[847]: [01038d66] +job attach(wpic-seo-mysql)
Feb 27 15:10:31 iZ23bojyn7vZ docker[847]: [info] POST /v1.15/containers/wpic-seo-mysql/stop?t=10
Feb 27 15:10:31 iZ23bojyn7vZ docker[847]: [01038d66] +job stop(wpic-seo-mysql)
Feb 27 15:10:31 iZ23bojyn7vZ docker[847]: Container already stopped
Feb 27 15:10:31 iZ23bojyn7vZ docker[847]: [01038d66] -job stop(wpic-seo-mysql) = ERR (1)
Feb 27 15:10:32 iZ23bojyn7vZ docker[1011]: wpic-seo-mysql
Feb 27 15:10:32 iZ23bojyn7vZ systemd[1]: Unit docker-mysql.service entered failed state.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, after updating a Centos 7 VM, Docker refuse to start.

TO solve this issue, try removing /var/run/docker.pid

```
rm /var/run/docker.pid
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but somehow the issue solved after I just update CentOS (Docker also updated).